# Put B balls in C containers. How many combinations have box(es) with exactly 2 balls?

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Assume that we have B balls (all the same) and C **numbered** containers (distinguishable). We want to calculate how many of the total combinations contain **exactly** 1 container with 2 balls, **exactly** 2 containers with 2 balls, etc.

The way I see it, first step is to calculate the different ways that we can distribute the B balls in C containers, assuming that each container can have **any** number of balls, including zero. According to the [Stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) paradigm, assuming that I am not making a mistake, this should be:
$\dbinom{B+C-1}{C-1}$

Second step is to calculate how many of those combinations have:

- exactly 1 container with 2 balls
- exactly 2 containers with 2 balls
- exactly 3 containers with 2 balls
- etc

which I have no idea how to do and any leads or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should go the other way: First, there are $\binom{C}{n}$ ways to choose which $n$ containers are to have exactly $2$ balls. Then use a modified stars and bars to calculate the number of ways to distribute the remaining $B-2n$ balls with none of the $C-n$ containers containing $2$ balls.

Comment: Finding the number of combinations where **exactly** 1 container has 2 balls is kind of tricky on its own. Maybe try finding the number of combinations where **at least** 1,2.. containers have 2 balls.

Comment: @Arthur I am not sure if I can do that, since there should be boxes with fewer than 2 balls (0, 1) and boxes with more than 2 (3, 4, ...). If it was just the "more" scenario I can see what you mean.

Comment: @genisage Actually like that I could produce a solution (not a scalable one but still a solution) by reaching the number of containers that produces 0 combinations, e.g. there are 0 combinations with at least X containers containing 2 balls, and work my way backwards: calculate the combinations for X-1 and know that this is actually for exactly X-1, calculate the combinations for X-2 and subtract that from that the X-1 to find the exact amount of X-2 and so on.

Comment: @George that was the idea. Your first attempt doesn't have to be scalable. And having any solution might help you see a pattern that helps you think of a simpler one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to use the generalized inclusion exclusion principle. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#A_generalization

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there have to be exactly $c$ containers containing $2$ balls. Choose these $c$ containers in one of ${C\choose c}$ ways, and put two balls in each of them. The numbers
$$C':=C-c, \quad B':=B-2c$$
remain fixed in the sequel.

There will be $m$ containers with $\geq3$ balls, where $m$ has to satisfy
$$0\leq m\leq M:=\min\left\{\biggl\lfloor{B'\over3}\biggr\rfloor, C'\right\}\ .$$
Choose these $m$ containers in one of ${C'\choose m}$ ways, and put three balls in each of them. Now there are $C'-m\geq0$ containers still empty, and there are $B'-3m\geq0$ balls left over.

We can decide to put a single ball into $k$ of the empty containers, where $k$ has to satisfy
$$0\leq k\leq k_m:=\min\{C'-m,B'-3m\}\ .$$ This can be done in ${C'-m\choose k}$ ways.

Now there are $B'-3m-k\geq0$ balls left, which can be freely distributed in the $m$ containers already holding $3$ balls. When $m\geq1$ this can be done in
$${B'-3m-k+(m-1)\choose m-1}={B'-2m-k-1\choose m-1}$$
ways; the case $m=0$ is special, see below.

Putting it all together the requested number $N$ comes to
$$N={C\choose c}\cdot\left({C'\choose B'}+\sum_{m=1}^M {C'\choose m}\sum_{k=0}^{k_m}      {C'-m\choose k}{B'-2m-k-1\choose m-1}\right)\ .$$
I don't think that the double sum can be simplified.